# Hibernate - Could not resolve root entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm getting a "Could not resolve root entity 'PlayerStats'" UnknownEntityException while try to load a entity with spezific uuid. Inside the Test-Section it works fine but in when I compile it and try to run I received the error.

PlayerStats

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedQueries;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table
@Entity
public class PlayerStats implements Serializable {

    public PlayerStats(String UUID, int deaths, int placed, int destroyed, String settings) {

        this.UUID = UUID;
        setDeaths(deaths);
        setPlaced(placedBlocks);
        setDestroyed(destroyed);
        setSettings(settings);
        stringToBool();
    }

    @Id
    @Column
    private String UUID;

    @Column
    private int deaths;

    @Column
    private int placed;

    @Column
    private int destroyed;

    @Column
    private String settings;

...
}
```

Test
//This works

```
@Test
    public void abc(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cl.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alldatanew");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread");

        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .addProperties(properties)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(PlayerStats.class)
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        SelectionQuery<PlayerStats> query = session.createSelectionQuery("FROM PlayerStats as P WHERE P.UUID = :uuid", PlayerStats.class);
        query.setParameter("uuid", "test3");
        PlayerStats playerStats = query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println(playerStats.getUUID());


    }
```

PlayerStatsStore
//This do not work

```
public PlayerStats findByUUID(String uuid) {

        try (Session session = openSession()) {
            SelectionQuery<PlayerStats> query = session.createSelectionQuery("FROM PlayerStats as P WHERE P.UUID = :uuid", PlayerStats.class);
            query.setParameter("uuid", uuid);
            PlayerStats playerStats = query.getSingleResult();
            return playerStats;
        } catch (final NoResultException exc) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The exception
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CztJW.png)
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXoy.png)

So my question is why it works inside of the test and not after compiling?
What am I doing wrong?

Regards, and thank you very much

I tried to solve my problem with the @NamedQuery annotation. This also doesn't work. So maybe my problem is at the SessionFactory init.

SessionFactory creation:

```
public SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Class<?>... clazz) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cl.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alldatanew");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addProperties(properties);
            for (Class<?> c : clazz) {
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(c.getClass());
            }
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a starting point, log each class you add by calling addAnnotatedClass to make sure that PlayerStats is actually added to the context. The error indicates that it is not.

Comment: @ewramner yes you are right. When I use this way to collecting the classes there are stored as java.lang.Class and not as my class. So now I fixed it and everything is fine. Best regards.

Comment: @ewramner can you please post your comment as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: please see my other answer below. I think that is better, as it shows the actual bug?

Comment: Your answer is not the solve. The problem is at the parameter collection for the consturctor. There I used 'Class<?>... clazz' which stores the classes in a lost of java.lang.Class ant not of the actuall class. So after I created a builder, so I can add the classes successively it works. You can edit your answer? So I can accept it, it was basiclly your idea.

Comment: I can, but the type of the collection should not matter. The type you actually pass to addAnnotatedClass matters and in your original code that was wrong as per the answer. Perhaps you could try just that fix to verify? You can always go back to the nicer builder code afterwards. I'm pretty sure this is the real solution.

Comment: @ewramner okay sorry nvm. I do not know what I did last time. I tried your answers and this works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: as written in the comments, make sure that addAnnotatedClass actually adds PlayerStats to the context. The error indicates that it has not been added.

Looking closer I think I spotted the bug in your original code. Change:

```
for (Class<?> c : clazz) {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(c.getClass());
}
```

To:

```
for (Class<?> c : clazz) {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(c);
}
```

You are already passing the classes, so the old code is registering the class of the class.